# MySql query to count the score of each user

Tags: mysql

The query needs to counts the total points for each user. For each qid the user with lower time gets a point and total point is sum of all the points. Below query just returns the total attempts for each user, need a way to return the points.

```
Incorrect Query=select user, count(*) from (select * from (select * from xyz order by 
time ASC) as temp1 group by temp1.user,temp1.qid) AS temp2 group by user
```

DB:

```
CREATE TABLE xyz (
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user VARCHAR(20),
  time INT,
  qid INT
);

INSERT INTO xyz VALUES (    1  ,  'abc' ,  15  , 1);
INSERT INTO xyz VALUES (    2  ,  'abc' ,  6  , 1);
INSERT INTO xyz VALUES (    3  ,  'xyz' ,  11  , 1);
INSERT INTO xyz VALUES (    4  ,  'abc' ,  4  , 1);
INSERT INTO xyz VALUES (    5  ,  'xyz' ,  13  , 2);
INSERT INTO xyz VALUES (    6  ,  'abc' ,  11  ,2);
INSERT INTO xyz VALUES (    7  ,  'abc' ,  9  , 3);
INSERT INTO xyz VALUES (    8  ,  'xyz' ,  10  , 3);
INSERT INTO xyz VALUES (    9  ,  'xyz' ,  2  , 3);
INSERT INTO xyz VALUES (    10  ,  'xyz' ,  2  , 4);
```

Expected output:

```
 USER   Score
 abc    2
 xyz    2
```

Output Explanation:

```
For qid=1, abc has lower time so 1 point to abc
For qid=2, abc has lower time so 1 point to abc
For qid=3, xyz has lower time so 1 point to xyz
For qid=4, xyz has lower time so 1 point to xyz
```

[sqlfiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0d6e)

Comment: so for each time < qid record the score of a user increases?

Comment: @blckbird for each qid the score of a user with lower time for that qid increases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find the number of times that a user is "first" for each `qid`.  Here is one method:

```
select xyz.user, count(*) as score
from xyz join
     (select qid, min(time) as mintime
      from xyz
      group by qid
     ) q
     on xyz.qid = q.qid and xyz.time = q.mintime
group by xyz.user;
```